# Knockout.js - Arrays/Object Literals and accessing a property for an audio path

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, mvvm, knockout.js

So, I've been taking some time to learn Knockout, and I'm enjoying myself so far. I've been looking for a good use case to use Knockout and I think I've found one in a guitar tuner Single Page Application.

Here's where I'm at:

- I currently have a guitar object that can handle adding another 'note' (arbitrarily set at an 'f').
- The guitar object is passed the number of strings, and an array of notes.
- in the UI I can see all the strings/notes

Here's my HTML and the Underlying js Model

```
    <!-- Scripts --> 
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/knockout-3.1.0.min.js"></script>        
    <script src="js/driver.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>

<!-- Pull the string data from the guitar object and populate it here. -->
<ul data-bind="foreach: guitars" class="guitars">
    <span>This is a <span data-bind="text: notes().length"></span> stringed guitar</span>
    <button data-bind="click: addNote">Addnote</button>
    <li>
        <ul data-bind="foreach: notes" class="audio-triggers">
            <li><a data-bind="text: $data" href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

... 

</body>
```

JS:
    $(document).ready(function(){

```
// Guitar Class that has its own note adder.    
var Guitar = function(strings, notes) {
    this.strings = strings;
    this.notes = ko.observableArray(notes);
    this.audioPaths = retrieveAudio(notes);

    this.addNote = function() {
        this.notes.push("f");
        this.strings = this.strings++; 
    }.bind(this);



}

// The view model is an abstract description of the state of the UI, but without any knowledge of the UI technology (HTML)
var viewModel = {
    guitars: [
        new Guitar(3, ["e", "a", "d"]),
        new Guitar(6, ["e", "a", "d", "a", "d", "g"])
    ]
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});

// Functions
function retrieveAudio(notes) {
var paths = {}

// For each note, access the audio path
$.each(notes, function(index, val){
    paths.note = val;
    paths.note.path = 'audio/1.mp3'
});

return paths;
```

}

Essentially I want to be able to take the array of notes, and determine audio paths using the name of the note as the name of the file, but I'm a little stuck because I'm unsure as to whether or not there's a "knockout" way of doing this.

My thought process was to just write an external function that would populate an object to return audio paths based on the note passed in, but again, I'm still unsure as to how I would access that in the corresponding HTML. because up to this point it's just been using data-binding on elements that aren't objects.

I guess my questions are:

1. Does it make sense to have the guitar 'object' to know about all the paths to its audio?
2. Can I `data-bind: foreach` through an object literal?
3. Does what I'm doing here resemble a best practice in any way?
4. Do I need to put audioPaths in a ko.observableArray?

I assume I'm going to access the note paths in a similar fashion to the way I accessed the notes array itself, with a foreach data bind. I guess my last question is, how am I going to access a nested property in an object literal (assuming I can `data-bind: foreach` through it?).

I appreciate any tips/hints/help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider converting the notes in the array in to individual objects that have their own path property.  If the path to the file can be calculated, then you can use a ko.computed to calculate the path based on the entities note value.

so you would end up with something like

```
// Guitar Class that has its own note adder.    
var Guitar = function (strings, notes) {
    var self = this;
    self.strings = strings;
    self.notes = ko.observableArray($.map(notes, function (item, index) {
        return new Note(item);
    }));

    self.addNote = function () {
        self.notes.push(new Note());
        self.strings = this.strings++;
    }.bind(self);
};

var Note = function (noteName) {
    var self = this;
    self.noteName = ko.observable(noteName || 'f');
    self.audioPath = ko.computed(function () {
        return 'audio/' + self.noteName() + '.mp3';
    });
};

// The view model is an abstract description of the state of the UI, but without any knowledge of the UI technology (HTML)
var viewModel = {
    guitars: [
    new Guitar(3, ["e", "a", "d"]),
    new Guitar(6, ["e", "a", "d", "a", "d", "g"])]
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gonefishern/8JvFV/2/)**

Comment: This pretty much answers my question and solves my issue, but if you'll humor my need to fully comprehend this:

My understanding is that we'll want to take an array of notes, and using $.map we take the values found in notes when a Guitar is constructed, and basically for each of those notes, we call the Note(item) constructor to give it a name and a path, and wrap that all in the observableArray since we want to observe changes on this collection?

Comment: I just need to make sure I'm thinking about this correctly! :)

Comment: yes, I think that you are on the right track. You basically want to convert the string note to a note object which gets added to the notes collection on the guitar object.